# Accessing local files via jupyter notebook on remote AWS server

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook, remote-server

I just setup ubuntu deep learning instance on AWS and would like to run my existing jupyter notebook there. Im working on creating CNN model on new images dataset.
Im stuck at reading my huge image files on my local drive from this remote server.
How can i read the files/folders on my local drive via this jupyter notebook on the instance?
Is there other solution than uploading the dataset?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/cli/

Comment: run aws cli from jupyter?

Answer (score 2):

Im not familiar yet with awscli, instead i transfer my dataset to the instance using winSCP. So far, it worked well. But i do appreciate for any advice, suggestion for any other methods that can be used besides winscp.